# React test vcoverage doesnot fulfill

Tags: reactjs

```
import React from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { compose } from 'recompose'

import { startWorkflow } from 'wf-dbd-react-ui/es/actions'
import Block from 'wf-dbd-react-ui/es/Block'
import BrowserTitle from 'wf-dbd-react-ui/es/BrowserTitle'
import ScrollToTopOnMount from 'wf-dbd-react-ui/es/ScrollToTopOnMount'
import FormMessages from 'wf-dbd-react-ui/es/FormMessages'
import { globals } from 'wf-dbd-react-ui/es/lib'
import withStrings from 'wf-dbd-react-ui/es/withStrings'

import PanelHeader from './panel-header/PanelHeader'
import AppHubTabs from './app-hub-tabs/AppHubTabs'
import RightRail from '../right-rail/RightRail'
import MessageDisplay from '../common/message-display/MessageDisplay'
import AddPayeeMessage from '../common/add-payee-message/AddPayeeMessage'
import { ADD_PAYEE, SEARCH_PAYEE } from '../workflows/add-payee/constants'
import ChangeFundingAccount from '../common/change-funding-account/ChangeFundingAccount'
import EditPaymentHotTaskModalContainer from '../common/hottask-edit-payment-modal/EditPaymentHotTaskModalContainer'
import DismissReminder from '../common/dismiss-reminder-modal/DismissReminder'
import HistoryTabViewPaymentDetailsModal from '../history-tab/group-history-form/history-tab-hot-task-menu/HistoryTabViewPaymentDetailsModal'

import * as actions from '../../lib/store/hub/actions'
import { getPayeeDetails } from '../../lib/store/payee-details/actions'
import { getPaymentDetails } from '../../lib/store/payment-details/actions'
import { resetPayeeTabFilterOption } from '../../lib/store/payees/actions'
import { closeViewPaymentDetailsModal } from '../../lib/store/history-tab/actions'
import { getHistoricalPayments } from '../../lib/selectors/selectors'

import styles from './AppHub.less'

class AppHub extends React.Component {

  componentDidMount() {
    const { getPayeeDetails, getPaymentDetails } = this.props
    // payee details need to be fetched unconditionally. the cache in saga ensures it is not fetched until required
    getPayeeDetails()
    getPaymentDetails()

    // Fix for for wide page layout issue in ie11 - Problem: ie11 nested flex element issue when window is minimized
    Iif (!!window.MSInputMethodContext && !!document.documentMode) { // will be true for only for ie11 browser
      document.querySelector('body > div > div > div > div').style.flexBasis = '0%'
    }
    // end of fix for ie11 wide page layout issue
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    const { clearMessages, resetPayeeTabFilterOption } = this.props
    clearMessages()
    //clearing the selected payees-tab filter option
    resetPayeeTabFilterOption()
  }

  handleTabSelect = activeTabIndexNew => {
    const { clearMessages, activeTabIndex, setActiveTabIndex } = this.props
    if (activeTabIndexNew !== activeTabIndex) {
      setActiveTabIndex(activeTabIndexNew)
      clearMessages()
    }
  }

  render() {
    const { activeTabIndex,
      getString,
      successMessage,
      errorMessage,
      ineligibleAccountMessage,
      payees,
      noOfHistoricalPayments,
      payeesLoaded,
      startAddPayeeWorkflow,
      shouldShowChangeAccount,
      reminderDismissalInProgress,
      reminderDueDate,
      closeViewPaymentDetailsModal,
      isViewPaymentDetailsModalOpen,
      viewPaymentData,
      showEditPaymentSeriesModal
    } = this.props
    const panelHeaderId = globals().billpayBusinessUser ? 'app.hub.business.bill.pay.header' : 'app.hub.bill.pay.header'
    return (
      <Block layout={true} horizontal={true}>
        <BrowserTitle title={getString('app.title')} />
        <ScrollToTopOnMount />
        <Block flex={true} relative={true} className={styles.billPayHub}>
          <PanelHeader headerId={panelHeaderId} />
          {
            successMessage &&
            <Block className={styles.message}>
              <MessageDisplay messages={successMessage} />
            </Block>
          }
          {
            errorMessage &&
            <Block className={styles.message}>
              <MessageDisplay messages={errorMessage} />
            </Block>
          }
          {
            ineligibleAccountMessage && globals().enableDisplayPayeesWithIneligibleAccounts &&
            <Block className={styles.message}>
              <MessageDisplay messages={ineligibleAccountMessage} focusOnMount={true} />
            </Block>
          }
          <Block className={styles.message}>
            <FormMessages formId="makePaymentForm" className="formMessages" />
          </Block>
          {payeesLoaded && payees.size === 0 && <AddPayeeMessage startAddPayeeWorkflow={startAddPayeeWorkflow} />}
          {payeesLoaded && (payees.size > 0 || noOfHistoricalPayments > 0) && (
            <AppHubTabs
              activeTabIndex={activeTabIndex}
              onTabSelect={this.handleTabSelect}
            />
          )
          }
        </Block>
        <Block relative={true} styles={styles.rightRailContainer}>
          <RightRail />
        </Block>
        {shouldShowChangeAccount && <ChangeFundingAccount />}
        {showEditPaymentSeriesModal && <EditPaymentHotTaskModalContainer />}
        {reminderDismissalInProgress && <DismissReminder dueDate={reminderDueDate} />}
        {isViewPaymentDetailsModalOpen &&
          <HistoryTabViewPaymentDetailsModal
            isOpen={isViewPaymentDetailsModalOpen}
            closeModal={closeViewPaymentDetailsModal}
            viewPaymentData={viewPaymentData}
          />
        }
      </Block>
    )
  }
}

AppHub.propTypes = {
  activeTabIndex: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
  payees: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  noOfHistoricalPayments: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
  payeesLoaded: PropTypes.bool,
  startAddPayeeWorkflow: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  errorMessage: PropTypes.object,
  successMessage: PropTypes.object,
  shouldShowChangeAccount: PropTypes.bool,
  resetPayeeTabFilterOption: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  getPayeeDetails: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  getPaymentDetails: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  clearMessages: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  setActiveTabIndex: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  getString: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  reminderDismissalInProgress: PropTypes.bool,
  reminderDueDate: PropTypes.string,
  closeViewPaymentDetailsModal: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  isViewPaymentDetailsModalOpen: PropTypes.bool,
  viewPaymentData: PropTypes.object,
  showEditPaymentSeriesModal: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  ineligibleAccountMessage: PropTypes.object
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  activeTabIndex: state.app.hub.activeHubTab,
  successMessage: state.app.hub.successMessage,
  errorMessage: state.app.hub.errorMessage,
  ineligibleAccountMessage: state.app.hub.ineligibleAccountMessage,
  payees: state.app.payees.payees,
  noOfHistoricalPayments: getHistoricalPayments(state),
  payeesLoaded: state.app.payees.payeesLoaded,
  shouldShowChangeAccount: state.app.hub.showChangeAccount,
  showEditPaymentSeriesModal: state.app.editPayment.editPaymentModal.isModalOpen,
  reminderDismissalInProgress: state.app.hub.reminderDismissalInProgress,
  reminderDueDate: state.app.hub.reminderDueDate,
  isViewPaymentDetailsModalOpen: state.app.historyTab.isViewPaymentDetailsModalOpen,
  viewPaymentData: state.app.historyTab.viewPaymentDetails
})

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  setActiveTabIndex: index => dispatch(actions.setHubActiveTab(index)),
  clearMessages: () => dispatch(actions.clearMessages()),
  startAddPayeeWorkflow: () => dispatch(startWorkflow({ name: ADD_PAYEE, startingView: SEARCH_PAYEE })),
  getPayeeDetails: () => dispatch(getPayeeDetails()),
  getPaymentDetails: () => dispatch(getPaymentDetails()),
  resetPayeeTabFilterOption: () => dispatch(resetPayeeTabFilterOption()),
  closeViewPaymentDetailsModal: () => dispatch(closeViewPaymentDetailsModal())
})

export default compose(withStrings, connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps))(AppHub)
```

iamtryingtofindasolutionpleasehelp.iamtryingtofindasolutionpleasehelp.iamtryingtofindasolutionpleasehelp.iamtryingtofindasolutionpleasehelp.iamtryingtofindasolutionpleasehelp.iamtryingtofindasolutionpleasehelp.iamtryingtofindasolutionpleasehelp.iamtryingtofindasolutionpleasehelp.iamtryingtofindasolutionpleasehelp.iamtryingtofindasolutionpleasehelp.iamtryingtofindasolutionpleasehelp.iamtryingtofindasolutionpleasehelp.iamtryingtofindasolutionpleasehelp.iamtryingtofindasolutionpleasehelp.iamtryingtofindasolutionpleasehelp.iamtryingtofindasolutionpleasehelp.iamtryingtofindasolutionpleasehelp.iamtryingtofindasolutionpleasehelp.iamtryingtofindasolutionpleasehelp.iamtryingtofindasolutionpleasehelp.iamtryingtofindasolutionpleasehelp.iamtryingtofindasolutionpleasehelp.iamtryingtofindasolutionpleasehelp.iamtryingtofindasolutionpleasehelp.iamtryingtofindasolutionpleasehelp.

```
import React from 'react'
import { mount } from 'enzyme'

import MockStoreProvider from 'wf-dbd-react-ui/es/MockStoreProvider'
import Immutable from 'immutable'

import AppHub from '../AppHub'
import AppHubTabs from '../app-hub-tabs/AppHubTabs'
import AddPayeeMessage from '../../common/add-payee-message/AddPayeeMessage'
import PanelHeader from '../panel-header/PanelHeader'

jest.mock('../panel-header/PanelHeader', () => () => 'PanelHeader')
jest.mock('../app-hub-tabs/AppHubTabs', () => () => 'AppHubTabs')
jest.mock('../../common/add-payee-message/AddPayeeMessage', () => () => 'AddPayeeMessage')
jest.mock('../../common/message-display/MessageDisplay', () => () => 'MessageDisplay')
jest.mock('../../right-rail/RightRail', () => () => 'RightRail')
jest.mock('../../history-tab/group-history-form/history-tab-hot-task-menu/HistoryTabViewPaymentDetailsModal', () => () => 'HistoryTabViewPaymentDetailsModal')

describe('AppHub', () => {

  let wrapper

  describe('when rendered without any payees and payments', () => {

    beforeEach(() => {
      const getString = jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => 'testString')
      const appState = {
        hub: {
          activeHubTab: 0,
          successMessage: { SuccessMessageBean: { globalMessages: [{ level: 'confirm', message: 'message' }] } },
          errorMessage: {}
        },
        payees: {
          payees: Immutable.List([]),
          enableSubmitBar: false,
          payeesLoaded: true
        },
        paymentAccounts: {
          paymentAccounts: Immutable.List([]),
          enableSubmitBar: false
        },
        scheduledPayments: {
          paymentsLoaded: false
        },
        historyTab: {
          isViewPaymentDetailsModalOpen: true,
          viewPaymentDetails: { key: 'value' },
          historicalPayments: {
            payments: []
          }
        },
        editPayment: {
          editPaymentModal: {
            isModalOpen: false
          }
        }
      }

      wrapper = mount(
        <MockStoreProvider appState={appState}>
          <AppHub getString={getString} />
        </MockStoreProvider>
      )
    })

    it('should be defined', () => {
      expect(AppHub).toBeDefined()
    })

    it('should render a PanelHeader', () => {
      expect(wrapper.find(PanelHeader)).toHaveLength(1)
    })

    it('should render AddPayeeMessage', () => {
      expect(wrapper.find(AddPayeeMessage)).toHaveLength(1)
    })

  })

  describe('when rendered without any payees and historical payments are present', () => {

    beforeEach(() => {
      const getString = jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => 'testString')
      const appState = {
        hub: {
          activeHubTab: 0,
          successMessage: { SuccessMessageBean: { globalMessages: [{ level: 'confirm', message: 'message' }] } },
          errorMessage: {}
        },
        payees: {
          payees: Immutable.List([]),
          enableSubmitBar: false,
          payeesLoaded: true
        },
        paymentAccounts: {
          paymentAccounts: Immutable.List([]),
          enableSubmitBar: false
        },
        scheduledPayments: {
          paymentsLoaded: false
        },
        historyTab: {
          isViewPaymentDetailsModalOpen: true,
          viewPaymentDetails: { key: 'value' },
          historicalPayments: {
            payments: [{
              mockKey: 'mockValue'
            }]
          }
        },
        editPayment: {
          editPaymentModal: {
            isModalOpen: false
          }
        }
      }

      wrapper = mount(
        <MockStoreProvider appState={appState}>
          <AppHub getString={getString} />
        </MockStoreProvider>
      )
    })
    it('should render AppHubTabs', () => {
      expect(wrapper.find(AppHubTabs)).toHaveLength(1)
    })

    it('should render AddPayeeMessage', () => {
      expect(wrapper.find(AddPayeeMessage)).toHaveLength(1)
    })
  })


  describe('when rendered with payees and there are no historical payments', () => {

    beforeEach(() => {
      const getString = jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => 'testString')
      const appState = {
        hub: {
          activeHubTab: 0,
          successMessage: { SuccessMessageBean: { globalMessages: [{ level: 'confirm', message: 'message' }] } },
          errorMessage: {}
        },
        payees: {
          payees: Immutable.List([{ id: 1 }]),
          enableSubmitBar: false,
          payeesLoaded: true
        },
        paymentAccounts: {
          paymentAccounts: Immutable.List([]),
          enableSubmitBar: false
        },
        scheduledPayments: {
          paymentsLoaded: false
        },
        historyTab: {
          isViewPaymentDetailsModalOpen: true,
          viewPaymentDetails: { key: 'value' },
          historicalPayments: {
            payments: []
          }
        },
        editPayment: {
          editPaymentModal: {
            isModalOpen: false
          }
        }
      }

      wrapper = mount(
        <MockStoreProvider appState={appState}>
          <AppHub getString={getString} />
        </MockStoreProvider>
      )
    })
    it('should render AppHubTabs', () => {
      expect(wrapper.find(AppHubTabs)).toHaveLength(1)
    })

    it('should render AddPayeeMessage', () => {
      expect(wrapper.find(AddPayeeMessage)).toHaveLength(0)
    })
  })

})
```

Comment: Some perl module available from [cpan](http://search.cpan.org) likely addresses the major part of the task - have you looked into [`Text::CSV`](http://search.cpan.org/~makamaka/Text-CSV-1.33/lib/Text/CSV.pm) ?

Comment: Hi collapsar,

If i am passing the data through ajax, does it mean i have the contents in text file at backend ?

How do i ensure that the data is stored in a text file first ?? Can you please suggest.....

Comment: Sending data through ajax just means to use a different front end to send a html form to the server - the backend format does not change, i.e. the parameter array of the POST request. It depends on your server-side programming environment how you access this array (eg. CGI.pm sports methods to iterate over all parameters or getting individual ones). Usually, you have to write data to the server file system yourself (excption: file uploads). However, with Text::CSV you would directly populate a 2-dim array and write that to a csv file.

Comment: Hello Collapsar,
Here is my SaveToCSV code below.. but the only difference here is that the below code takes json data and converts to csv.  can you tell me wat to edit here for my situation. since i already have csv data, what will my modified code look like >?

Comment: @collapsar
Here is the code 

'sub SaveJsonToCSV{

    my $file=$_[0];
    print header('application/json');
    
  
     my $q = CGI->new;
     my $data = decode_json($q->param('data'));

     my @rows;

 $count=scalar @{$data};
 push(@rows,[keys($data->[0])]);
 push(@rows,[values($data->[$_])]) for 0 .. $count-1;
    
    my $csv = Text::CSV->new ( { always_quote => 0,eol => "\n" } );
   open $fh, '>', $file or die $!;
  $csv->print( $fh, $_ ) for @rows; 
 close $fh or die "new.csv: $!";
     print '{"suc":true}'; 
}
'

Comment: Basically your code looks ok, but the actual answer depends on what `decode_json` returns. CSV is rather a simple way to organize data but a data format on its own, apart from escaping the few characters carrying special semantics (field separator, delimiter, escape character) which `Text::CSV`abstracts away. Do you get unexpected results? Are errors thrown? Is the JSON data correct?

Comment: @collapsar- i am able to send json data through ajax now. When i enter url: and give trhe path name and action=SavetoCSV., it should direct this transferred data to method -> SavetoCSV.... am i right ??

how will i know whether this perl method is called or not ? is there a way i can print anything to the web page for troubleshooting. 

Can you provide me your skype id. if its okay with you, i can add you on skype and show you the error i am facing. you could solve it in a few mns and it would really help me. :(